# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'BGColors'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to convert the following React component to TypeScript:

```
import clsx from 'clsx'

type BGColors = {
    amber: string
    emerald: string
    fuchsia: string
    indigo: string
    lightBlue: string
    purple: string
    rose: string
}

const codeBackground: BGColors = {
    amber: 'bg-amber-500',
    emerald: 'bg-emerald-500',
    fuchsia: 'bg-fuchsia-400',
    indigo: 'bg-indigo-400',
    lightBlue: 'bg-light-blue-500',
    purple: 'bg-purple-400',
    rose: 'bg-rose-400',
}

const previewBackground: BGColors & { gray: string } = {
    amber: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-amber-50 to-amber-100',
    emerald: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-emerald-50 to-teal-100',
    fuchsia: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-fuchsia-50 to-fuchsia-100',
    gray: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-50 to-gray-100',
    indigo: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-50 to-indigo-100',
    lightBlue: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-light-blue-50 to-light-blue-100',
    purple: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-50 to-purple-100',
    rose: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-rose-50 to-rose-100',
}

type CodeSampleProps = {
    preview: string
    snippet: string
    previewClassName: string
    color: string
}

export const CodeSample = ({
    preview,
    snippet,
    previewClassName,
    color = 'gray',
}: CodeSampleProps) => {
    return (
        <div className="relative mb-8 overflow-hidden">
            <div
                className={clsx(
                    'rounded-t-xl overflow-hidden',
                    previewBackground[color],
                    previewClassName,
                    {
                        'p-10': !previewClassName,
                    }
                )}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: preview }}
            />
            <div
                className={clsx('overflow-hidden rounded-b-xl', codeBackground[color], {
                    'bg-gray-800': !codeBackground[color],
                })}
            >
                <pre
                    className={clsx(
                        'scrollbar-none overflow-x-auto p-6 text-sm leading-snug language-html text-white',
                        {
                            'bg-black bg-opacity-75': codeBackground[color],
                        }
                    )}
                >
                    <code className="language-html" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: snippet }} />
                </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

It gives me the following error on `codeBackground[color]`:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'BGColors'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'BGColors'.ts(7053)

I also get 3 other errors on anything that uses `[color]` ,i.e, `previewBackground[color]` & `codeBackground[color]`

How do I solve it?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Nope. My code is right as they're supposed to be objects. Also, I used VSCode's autocomplete type-suggestions to add it so I don't think it's wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was a bug in the code as I just copied it from someone's JS project. TS made me catch the error.

I changed my code to check if `gray` exists on `codeBackground[color]` & it got rid of the error.

Here's the code:

```
import clsx from 'clsx'

type BGColors = {
    amber: string
    emerald: string
    fuchsia: string
    gray: string
    indigo: string
    lightBlue: string
    purple: string
    rose: string
}

const codeBackground: Omit<BGColors, 'gray'> = {
    amber: 'bg-amber-500',
    emerald: 'bg-emerald-500',
    fuchsia: 'bg-fuchsia-400',
    // gray: 'bg-gray-400',
    indigo: 'bg-indigo-400',
    lightBlue: 'bg-light-blue-500',
    purple: 'bg-purple-400',
    rose: 'bg-rose-400',
}

const previewBackground: BGColors = {
    amber: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-amber-50 to-amber-100',
    emerald: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-emerald-50 to-teal-100',
    fuchsia: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-fuchsia-50 to-fuchsia-100',
    gray: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-50 to-gray-100',
    indigo: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-50 to-indigo-100',
    lightBlue: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-light-blue-50 to-light-blue-100',
    purple: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-50 to-purple-100',
    rose: 'bg-gradient-to-r from-rose-50 to-rose-100',
}

type CodeSampleProps = {
    preview: string
    snippet: string
    previewClassName: string
    color: keyof BGColors
}

export const CodeSample = ({
    preview,
    snippet,
    previewClassName,
    color = 'gray',
}: CodeSampleProps) => {
    return (
        <div className="relative mb-8 overflow-hidden">
            <div
                className={clsx(
                    'rounded-t-xl overflow-hidden',
                    previewBackground[color],
                    previewClassName,
                    {
                        'p-10': !previewClassName,
                    }
                )}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: preview }}
            />
            <div
                className={clsx(
                    'overflow-hidden rounded-b-xl',
                    color === 'gray' ? '' : codeBackground[color],
                    {
                        'bg-gray-800': color === 'gray' ? '' : !codeBackground[color],
                    }
                )}
            >
                <pre
                    className={clsx(
                        'scrollbar-none overflow-x-auto p-6 text-sm leading-snug language-html text-white',
                        {
                            'bg-black bg-opacity-75': color === 'gray' ? '' : codeBackground[color],
                        }
                    )}
                >
                    <code className="language-html" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: snippet }} />
                </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you comment more of what it did exactly? I am struggling with similar issue and have no idea how to fix it

Comment: @KlimYadrintsev this was 3 years ago. idk maybe the `color === 'gray'` was the fix. post your own question... i'm sure you'll find an answer. just realized you commented 1 month ago too lol.